# Can I use Xamarin.Android trial version for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, trial

Can I use Xamarin.Android trial version for Xamarin.Forms?

I'm getting the following error:

```
Build failed. See the build log for details:

System.ArgumentException: minimumEdition
в Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationReason..ctor(XamarinProduct product, Restriction restriction, XamarinEdition minimumEdition, String errorText, String errorCode, String restrictedItem)
```

Where I can find Xamarin.Forms trial version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the website https://xamarin.com/starter

> Apps must meet size restrictions(128k of compiled C# or F# code), include only managed code (not Objective-C/Swift, Java, or C/C++ libraries), and use Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android, **not Xamarin.Forms**.

When you use the **Trial** version then you should be able to use Xamarin.Forms as mentioned here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/beginning_a_xamarin_trial/

Ask the support in case you have problems with your license. They're going to help you quickly.